# python: is there any function that allows you to start a new line in easygui?

Tags: python, python-3.x, easygui

if I wanted an output to be completely string, is there a function that works in a similar way to < br > or < /br > does in html?

for example:

```
"hello <br> my <br> friend"
```

would be output as:

```
hello
my
friend
```

but for easygui in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `\n` (newline) instead of `<br>`